# Copy cells values faster

Tags: excel, vba

I am new here and I hope I will explain properly my simple code below. So what the code does is to simple copy the values from specific columns and paste them as values to other columns in the same worksheet. The reason why I have this code is to help the users avoid inserting the same data multiple times.

The code I have works, however, it takes quite time to copy-paste the values to other columns (around 10-12seconds). Is it possible to make this work faster? Or there is another approach of creating this and work faster?

Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Session").Range("a1:a2000").Copy
    Sheets("Session").Range("y1, af1, cw1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Session").Range("b1:b2000").Copy
    Sheets("Session").Range("ab1, ac1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Session").Range("v1:v2000").Copy
    Sheets("Session").Range("bg1, bs1, ca1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Session").Range("g5:g2000").Copy
    Sheets("Session").Range("ba1, bc1, be1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Session").Range("t1:t2000").Copy
    Sheets("Session").Range("di1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Session").Range("x1:x2000").Copy
    Sheets("Session").Range("cx1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues



End Sub
```

Comment: just a note: you should only do one `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in the beginning and one `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` in the end before `End Sub` and omit all the others.

Comment: @Peh - thanks. Changed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer values directly without copy and paste, which is quicker, even though this method will result in more lines. The With statements do not I believe make for more efficient code, but they do make for tidier code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Session")
    With .Range("a1:a2000")
        .Range("y1").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
        .Range("af1").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
        .Range("cw1").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
    With .Range("b1:b2000")
        'etc
    End With
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line at the beginning (after private sub):

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

and this one at the end of your code (before end sub):

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Disabling auto-calculation should speed up the copy-paste process.

Comment: didn't change much. Thanks for your help!